# Django losing session state?

Tags: django, apache, cookies, session-cookies

I have a VPS running apache. Apache is serving two domains, my homepage (django, django-cms, zinnia) and a prod site (django, oscar). I use falkon browser.

When I change the items in site's admin (I change values in a row, it's list_editable, and then click Save), sometimes (quite often), the response returned is a redirect to login, as if the session cookie is not passed. What is interesting, if I save the POST request as curl and retry it, it succeeds. Since there are several redirects after I hit save, I've seen it failing on the first one (so the item is not saved), or the second one (the item is therefore saved, but I find myself not on the list page, but on the main admin page).

How do I debug it? Or maybe someone has seen this behaviour before.

Updates:

1. I've run through mitmproxy, the headers and cookies seem ok.
2. The current settings is [here](https://kupec.info/static/settings.tgz).
3. I've installed django-debug-toolbar, haven't seen the problem yet, but probably because of the heavy interception.

Comment: which server u are using? And can you share setting.py file for better understanding of issue

Comment: Hi, @VinitaSonakiya! I'm not sure what is meant by server, but it's VPS (wedos) with gentoo. About settings, they're quite big and split across multiple files, not sure about the best way to share them. I'll try to tgz and put on the website though.

Comment: This issue can be related to SECRET_KEY of django. If you are using random SECRET_KEY and multiple worker process, web request may fail intermittently. if that is the case try to keep SECRET_KEY static some thing like SECRET_KEY="xCcXB4YDfsnpYcg7oyeWYGE6kpVZuTsw" and check issue still persists

Comment: The SECRET_KEY is static in settings, and it different for my two domains.